# Media APIでのローカルの音声ファイル呼び出しに関して

Tags: monaca

Monacaで英単語アプリの開発を考えているのですが、単語の音声として、Media APIを使ってローカルにある音声ファイルを再生させるようにしたいと思っています。ファイルサイズ的にどの程度の容量がおけるなどの制限はあったりするのでしょうか？（ローカルなので制限はなさそうとも考えていますが。。。)Monacaは初めてさわるので、初歩的な質問で大変恐れ入りますが、どなたかご教示頂けましたら幸いです。

Answer (score 1):

プログラム、リソースを含めて50MB以内を推奨します。
現在は4GBまでパッケージに出来ますが、
ダウンロードに時間がかかるのと、端末の容量を圧迫するのでお勧めしません。
どれくらいの単語数を登録するのか分かりませんが、
相当量の音声ファイルでしたらストリーミングした方が良いかと思います。
また、ファイルを端末に保存し、その後再生する方法もありますので、
再生する際に逐次ダウンロードを考察するのもありかもしれません。
FileTransfer( http://docs.monaca.mobi/3.5/ja/reference/phonegap_34/ja/file-transfer/ )を確認してください。